# IP Camera suddenly stopped transmitting outside of the network

Tags: security

I have an IP Camera linked to AngelCam it has been running for over a year. Last night it suddenly went off and I can't understand why. The internal port is 192.168.0.42:80 I have forwarded this port to [external ip]:80 this has run fine until last night.

I bought the camera for about £15 on amazon the device ID is C6F0SeZ3N0P5L0 (According to the device information on the dashboard) and it uses HiCam software.

If I type the local IP into the browser I enter my credentials and I see the camera dashboard, then I have 2 options Web View or Mobile view. Both work fine and transmit videos on the local IP.

What is strange though is if I type the external IP and port I see the dashboard (this says the port forwarding is working fine.) However, the camera feed does not work. However if I click mobile view I can see the feed.

Has anybody experienced anything like this before and does it sound like I have missed something.

Comment: This is not a DIY/Home-Improvement question. Try [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here.

> I bought the camera for about £15

Most likely, this is your problem.  I spent a few minutes perusing the IP cameras on Amazon, and £15 is the bottom, bottom, bottom of the barrel.  This thing is simply too cheap to have any expectation of reliability.

The wisdom of scraping the bottom of the barrel is arguable. What's not arguable is that it's definitely not worth sinking your precious time into troubleshooting it.  **The normal expectation is that when it breaks, you throw it out and buy another one**.  Once you are sick of this merry go round, you buy a better one.

> The internal port is 192.168.0.42:80 I have forwarded this port to [external ip]:80

OK, so you exposed the camera to the public internet.  I'm really not sure why, the camera should be initiating contact with AngelCam, and that should work  just fine through a NAT/router; there's no reason or need for Angelcam to initiate contact with the camera so no reason for the camera to be publicly exposed.

Anyway, by leaving it publicly exposed, someone scanning IP addresses (note your public IP is IPv4, which makes it easy to scan) probably found your camera, threw the usual exploits at it, found a vulnerability, and either own your camera, or accidentally broke it by their cracking.  Because manufacturers of $15 cameras don't issue patches, even if you were faithful in patching.

(By the way, this is how small businesses go bankrupt.  Some silly thing like this is overlooked in their PCI-DSS self-inspect, it gets used as a gateway to hack a credit card machine, etc...)

In the future, don't forward public ports for security cameras.  Get cameras smart enough not to need that.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. My father has the same cameras and his begun doing the same thing since the weekend also. I don't know what this issue is, but you have highlighted a few issues I should be addressing. AngelCam supply a raspberry pi image that scans the internal network for a camera feed and exposes that securely direct to AngelCam I will explore this tonight.

I appreciate the verbosity of your answer and it has given me a lot to think about.